# Regex From .NET to Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression which works perfectly well (although I am sure it is weak) in .NET/C#:

```
((^|\s))(?<tag>\@(?<tagname>(\w|\+)+))(?($|\s|\.))
```

I am trying to move it over to Python, but I seem to be running into a formatting issue (invalid expression exception).

It is a lame question/request, but I have been staring at this for a while, but nothing obvious is jumping out at me.

Note: I am simply trying

```
r = re.compile('((^|\s))(?<tag>\@(?<tagname>(\w|\+)+))(?($|\s|\.))')
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing /...(?(...))/? If I remember correctly, (?) is a non-capturing group, and then you are doing () which captures, am I just missing something?

Comment: In fact, `(?:)` is a non-capturing group according to the documentation I found. `(?)` does not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax incompatibilities between .NET regexps and PCRE/Python regexps :

- `(?<name>...)` is `(?P<name>...)`
- `(?...)` does not exist, and as I don't know what it is used for in .NET I can't guess any equivalent. A Google codesearch do not give me any pointer to what it could be used for.

Besides, you should use Python raw strings (`r"I am a raw string"`) instead of normal strings when expressing regexps : raw strings do not interpret escape sequences (like `\n`). But it is not the problem in your example as you're not using any known escape sequence which could be replaced (`\s` does not mean anything as an escape sequence, so it is not replaced).

Answer (score 0):

Is "(?" there to prevent creation of a separate group?  In Python's re's, this is "(:?".  Try this:

```
r = re.compile(r'((^|\s))(:?<tag>\@(:?<tagname>(\w|\+)+))(:?($|\s|\.))')
```

Also, note the use of a raw string literal (the "r" character just before the quotes).  Raw literals suppress `'\'` escaping, so that your `'\'` characters pass straight through to re (otherwise, you'd need `'\\'` for every `'\'`).

Comment: Noncapturing group in .net is (?:)

Comment: The tip on raw strings was very helpful. As delroth mentions the main issue was related to ?P<name> instead of ?<name>